# VS Test failing in Pipelines with missing 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm getting a failed builds due to the *Visual Studio Test* step failing in my Build Pipeline.

I have a simple .NET Core v2.1 class library and associated MS Test library. I have 2 steps in my pipeline:

1. A .NET Core build step, and
2. A Visual Studio Test step

Both projects target the `netcoreapp2.1` framework, see below for `.csproj` files.

I have tried enabling and disabling the *Code coverage* option, but this make no difference.

Thanks in advance,

Kaine

---

**.csproj files**

*Main Project*

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>Trustmarque.Core.ExtensionMethods</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>Trustmarque.Core.ExtensionMethods</RootNamespace>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Description>Generalised class extension methods build on the .NET Core.</Description>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

*Test Project*

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>

    <AssemblyName>Trustmarque.Core.ExtensionMethods.Tests</AssemblyName>

    <RootNamespace>Trustmarque.Core.ExtensionMethods.Tests</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.3.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ExtensionMethods\ExtensionMethods.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

---

**YAML**

```
queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands: vstest

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: '.NET Core Build'


- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VS Unit Test'
  inputs:
    testFiltercriteria: /diag

    codeCoverageEnabled: true

    otherConsoleOptions: '/framework:".NETCoreApp,Version=2.1"'
```

---

**Test Output Log**

```
2018-11-14T09:33:56.0414482Z ##[section]Starting: VS Unit Test
2018-11-14T09:33:56.0420823Z ==============================================================================
2018-11-14T09:33:56.0420887Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
2018-11-14T09:33:56.0420941Z Description  : Run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio Test (VsTest) runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as MsTest, xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah (for JavaScript tests using QUnit, Mocha and Jasmine), etc. can be run. Tests can be distributed on multiple agents using this task (version 2).
2018-11-14T09:33:56.0420983Z Version      : 2.142.12
2018-11-14T09:33:56.0421033Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-11-14T09:33:56.0421089Z Help         : [More information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)
2018-11-14T09:33:56.0421126Z ==============================================================================
2018-11-14T09:33:56.9036862Z SystemVssConnection exists true
2018-11-14T09:33:57.0359241Z SystemVssConnection exists true
2018-11-14T09:33:57.1181619Z Running tests using vstest.console.exe runner.
2018-11-14T09:33:57.1181728Z ======================================================
2018-11-14T09:33:57.1182048Z Test selector : Test assemblies
2018-11-14T09:33:57.1182141Z Test filter criteria : null
2018-11-14T09:33:57.1182212Z Search folder : D:\a\1\s
2018-11-14T09:33:57.1182743Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8312901Z Run in parallel : false
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8314015Z Run in isolation : false
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8315114Z Path to custom adapters : null
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8319882Z Other console options : /framework:".NETCoreApp,Version=2.1"
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8320427Z Code coverage enabled : true
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8320689Z Diagnostics enabled : false
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8322155Z SystemVssConnection exists true
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8348561Z Run the tests locally using vstest.console.exe
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8348848Z ========================================================
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8349439Z Test selector : Test assemblies
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8352816Z Test assemblies : **\*test*.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8353669Z Test filter criteria : null
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8360790Z Search folder : D:\a\1\s
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8361971Z Run settings file : D:\a\1\s
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8369736Z Run in parallel : false
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8370326Z Run in isolation : false
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8392182Z Path to custom adapters : null
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8393171Z Other console options : /framework:".NETCoreApp,Version=2.1"
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8395168Z Code coverage enabled : true
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8396140Z Diagnostics enabled : false
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8398717Z Rerun failed tests: false
2018-11-14T09:33:57.8401805Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
2018-11-14T09:33:58.9933609Z ========================================================
2018-11-14T09:33:58.9973631Z ======================================================
2018-11-14T09:33:59.0613609Z [command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" @D:\a\_temp\69e3bc61-e7f0-11e8-8572-4338aa006dd6.txt
2018-11-14T09:34:06.3128046Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.8.0
2018-11-14T09:34:06.3130539Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2018-11-14T09:34:06.3131113Z 
2018-11-14T09:34:06.6145727Z vstest.console.exe 
2018-11-14T09:34:06.6146432Z "D:\a\1\s\ExtensionMethods.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll"
2018-11-14T09:34:06.6147591Z "D:\a\1\s\ExtensionMethods.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll"
2018-11-14T09:34:06.6147793Z "D:\a\1\s\ExtensionMethods.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Trustmarque.Core.ExtensionMethods.Tests.dll"
2018-11-14T09:34:06.6149501Z /EnableCodeCoverage
2018-11-14T09:34:06.6149657Z /logger:"trx"
2018-11-14T09:34:06.6149783Z /TestAdapterPath:"D:\a\1\s"
2018-11-14T09:34:06.6149907Z /framework:".NETCoreApp,Version=2.1"
2018-11-14T09:34:12.8077290Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2018-11-14T09:34:14.8437128Z Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.
2018-11-14T09:34:14.8437793Z Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll is built for Framework 4.5 and Platform AnyCPU.
2018-11-14T09:34:14.8438215Z Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll is built for Framework 1.5 and Platform AnyCPU.
2018-11-14T09:34:14.8438617Z Go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236877&clcid=0x409 for more details on managing these settings.
2018-11-14T09:34:14.8438786Z 
2018-11-14T09:34:23.5616980Z M i c r o s o f t   ( R )   C o v e r a g e   C o l l e c t i o n   T o o l   V e r s i o n   1 5 . 0 . 3 0 3 1 9 . 0 
2018-11-14T09:34:23.5617265Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:23.5617351Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:23.5617457Z  C o p y r i g h t   ( c )   M i c r o s o f t   C o r p o r a t i o n .     A l l   r i g h t s   r e s e r v e d . 
2018-11-14T09:34:23.5617498Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:23.5617554Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:23.5617591Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:23.5617627Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:24.4903850Z  2.8847
2018-11-14T09:34:25.4504736Z System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find tests for D:\a\1\s\ExtensionMethods.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll. Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" and framework version settings are appropriate. Rerun with /diag option to diagnose further.
2018-11-14T09:34:25.4504927Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.GetTestHostProcessStartInfo(IEnumerable`1 sources, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, TestRunnerConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
2018-11-14T09:34:25.4505025Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources)
2018-11-14T09:34:25.4505077Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsHandler eventHandler)
2018-11-14T09:34:25.6678123Z M i c r o s o f t   ( R )   C o v e r a g e   C o l l e c t i o n   T o o l   V e r s i o n   1 5 . 0 . 3 0 3 1 9 . 0 
2018-11-14T09:34:25.6678286Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:25.6678334Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:25.6678492Z  C o p y r i g h t   ( c )   M i c r o s o f t   C o r p o r a t i o n .     A l l   r i g h t s   r e s e r v e d . 
2018-11-14T09:34:25.6678566Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:25.6678623Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:25.6678664Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:25.6678700Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:26.8351769Z  M i c r o s o f t   ( R )   C o v e r a g e   C o l l e c t i o n   T o o l   V e r s i o n   1 5 . 0 . 3 0 3 1 9 . 0 
2018-11-14T09:34:26.8351940Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:26.8352006Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:26.8352092Z  C o p y r i g h t   ( c )   M i c r o s o f t   C o r p o r a t i o n .     A l l   r i g h t s   r e s e r v e d . 
2018-11-14T09:34:26.8352125Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:26.8352155Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:26.8352199Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:26.8352227Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:26.8788931Z  2.3838
2018-11-14T09:34:26.8898822Z System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find tests for D:\a\1\s\ExtensionMethods.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll. Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" and framework version settings are appropriate. Rerun with /diag option to diagnose further.
2018-11-14T09:34:26.8899122Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.GetTestHostProcessStartInfo(IEnumerable`1 sources, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, TestRunnerConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
2018-11-14T09:34:26.8899942Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources)
2018-11-14T09:34:26.8900007Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsHandler eventHandler)
2018-11-14T09:34:26.9247283Z M i c r o s o f t   ( R )   C o v e r a g e   C o l l e c t i o n   T o o l   V e r s i o n   1 5 . 0 . 3 0 3 1 9 . 0 
2018-11-14T09:34:26.9247370Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:26.9247428Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:26.9247520Z  C o p y r i g h t   ( c )   M i c r o s o f t   C o r p o r a t i o n .     A l l   r i g h t s   r e s e r v e d . 
2018-11-14T09:34:26.9247570Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:26.9247619Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:26.9247650Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:26.9247681Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:27.4568128Z  M i c r o s o f t   ( R )   C o v e r a g e   C o l l e c t i o n   T o o l   V e r s i o n   1 5 . 0 . 3 0 3 1 9 . 0 
2018-11-14T09:34:27.4568259Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:27.4568335Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:27.4568442Z  C o p y r i g h t   ( c )   M i c r o s o f t   C o r p o r a t i o n .     A l l   r i g h t s   r e s e r v e d . 
2018-11-14T09:34:27.4568504Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:27.4568543Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:27.4568580Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:27.4568631Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:27.5016363Z  3.0114
2018-11-14T09:34:33.4517174Z M i c r o s o f t   ( R )   C o v e r a g e   C o l l e c t i o n   T o o l   V e r s i o n   1 5 . 0 . 3 0 3 1 9 . 0 
2018-11-14T09:34:33.4517363Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:33.4517409Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:33.4517517Z  C o p y r i g h t   ( c )   M i c r o s o f t   C o r p o r a t i o n .     A l l   r i g h t s   r e s e r v e d . 
2018-11-14T09:34:33.4517603Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:33.4517641Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:33.4517678Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:33.4517715Z  
2018-11-14T09:34:33.7048135Z  Passed   Timestamp_DateTime_CurrentDateTime_FormatAndValuesMatch
2018-11-14T09:34:33.7048569Z Passed   ToJson_Object_ReturnsStringRepresentation
2018-11-14T09:34:33.7048660Z Passed   ToJsonString_Object_ReturnsStringRepresentationIncludingObjectType
2018-11-14T09:34:33.7049036Z Passed   IsNullOrEmpty_String_EmptyAndNullValues
2018-11-14T09:34:33.7049135Z Passed   IsNullOrEmpty_String_NonEmptyOrNullValues
2018-11-14T09:34:33.7049190Z Passed   Parse_String_ValidTypeParses_CorrectTypes
2018-11-14T09:34:33.7049257Z Passed   Parse_String_ValidTypeParses_DefaultTypes
2018-11-14T09:34:33.7049297Z Passed   FromJson_String_ValidObjects
2018-11-14T09:34:33.7049338Z Passed   FromJson_String_InvalidObjects
2018-11-14T09:34:33.7049402Z Passed   IsValidEmailAddress_String_ValidEmailAddresses_ReturnTrue
2018-11-14T09:34:33.7049465Z Passed   IsValidEmailAddress_String_InvalidEmailAddresses_ReturnFalse
2018-11-14T09:34:35.8172642Z Results File: D:\a\1\s\TestResults\VssAdministrator_factoryvm-az552_2018-11-14_09_34_33.trx
2018-11-14T09:34:35.8203749Z 
2018-11-14T09:34:35.8210373Z Attachments:
2018-11-14T09:34:35.8210758Z   D:\a\1\s\TestResults\6c92c0b5-2e35-48af-867a-2a4575306a68\VssAdministrator_factoryvm-az552 2018-11-14 09_34_22.coverage
2018-11-14T09:34:35.8211079Z 
2018-11-14T09:34:35.8211397Z Total tests: Unknown. Passed: 11. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
2018-11-14T09:34:35.8211670Z Test Run Aborted.
2018-11-14T09:34:35.8211939Z Test execution time: 10.7395 Seconds
2018-11-14T09:34:36.0240507Z ##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
2018-11-14T09:34:36.0769776Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe failed with return code: 1
2018-11-14T09:34:36.3170630Z ##[error]VsTest task failed.
2018-11-14T09:34:36.3566464Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
2018-11-14T09:34:36.4181634Z Publishing test results to test run '6'
2018-11-14T09:34:36.4181725Z Test results remaining: 11. Test run id: 6
2018-11-14T09:34:36.9962474Z Published Test Run : https://dev.azure.com/TrustmarqueIT/Test_2018-10-30/_TestManagement/Runs#runId=6&_a=runCharts
2018-11-14T09:34:36.9971952Z ##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
2018-11-14T09:34:36.9972803Z ##[section]Finishing: VS Unit Test
```

Comment: Did you try to add `dotnet restore` task before your `dotnet build` in order to make sure the dependencies were installed correctly?

Comment: Hi @Jayendran, thanks for your suggestion. I didn't have a `dotnet restore` step, added it, but it still fails. Here's the YAML:          
`resources:
- repo: self
queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands: vstest

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: '.NET Core Restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: '.NET Core Build'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VS Unit Test'
  inputs:
    testFiltercriteria: /diag
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    otherConsoleOptions: '/framework:".NETCoreApp,Version=2.1"'`

Comment: Have you tried the default .NET Core build-pipeline template?  Does that work without changing anything?

Comment: Hi @JonathanTwite, I think that you are talking about the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` step in the original YAML. This is the standard .NET Core build-pipeline template as far as I know. This by itself works without issue. The problem comes when I add the test step. Also, using the standard *Azure Repos* build template runs perfectly, but won't run the test steps as it builds on Ubuntu and the only way to add the Test step or change the vmImage is to edit the YAML, an area of expertise that I seriously lack... ;-)

Comment: I was suggesting you try the build template (full build, not single task) provided in the DevOps front-end, rather than writing the YAML yourself - then if that works, you can compare.

Comment: I'm afraid that, being a bit of a NOOB, I'm not quite following you @JonathanTwite. Do you mean [this option](https://www.screencast.com/t/YqOneMW9)?

Comment: any luck with this ???

Comment: Hi @Gurpreet, I did make progress on this, yes. I didn't quite grasp the suggestions being made by Jonathan Twite, so persevered a little further until I reached a solution. I'll detail an answer, which I should have done, so thanks for prompting me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks @Gurpreet for prompting me to document my solution.

It's been quite a while, so my memory of the steps is a bit shaky, but I believe that my mistake was thinking that, on the first screen after selecting a source repository, I assumed the templates listed were all that was available and that `Empty job` was the same as the `YAML` template. I'd *incorrectly assumed* that Empty job meant that I'd have to edit the YAML myself.

Jonathan Twite gave me some great pointers but I didn't quite grasp what he was suggesting at the time.

### The Solution

Anyway, the solution was to select either `Empty job` or scroll to the bottom and select `Empty pipeline`, why they're referred to by different names is a mystery.

[image: Choose Empty job or Empty pipeline]

After selecting the empty template, the next screen provides you with a default Agent job. Clicking the plus, you can add a variety of different tasks. This was part of my original mistake, I confused the tasks with the templates on the previous screen.

I added the `.NET Core` task.

[image: Add the .NET Core task to the Agent job]

I changed the `Display name` and the `Command`, as well as making sure that the `Version` was correct. Interestingly, the `Command` has a number of interesting options, three of which that I found useful are:

- restore
- build
- test

So, rather than adding a specific *Test* task, you add the *.NET Core* task and configure it to do the test bit. This was a bit confusing for me, I didn't realise that the *.NET Core* task was capable of doing the testing as well.

[image: Configure the .NET Core task to either a restore, build or test step]

In my case, I also started testing the ability to deploy NuGet packages, but that's a whole other can of worms.

I hope that this has helped, and wish you all good luck with your projects.

Kaine

Comment: After hours and hours of research this solved my problem: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3569

Answer (score 49):

I have solved my problem by revising my filter to find test assemblies. When i was messing around with my test step, accidentally set the filter to "/**/*UnitTests*.dll" and i did not realise that it was also matching UnitTests.dll in the "obj" folder and that folder does not have .deps.json files. From the logs i noticed that it was running tests twice (once for each matching dll) so then i ignored the obj folder by reverting back my filter to exclude obj folder. So i guess two things to take care in such cases,

1. You must have "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" installed on your test
   project and
2. Your filter does not include or exclude any unwanted
   dll(s) which you (don't want / want to) be there

Comment: Nice one @Gurpreet. You can see that, in the example I posted, I filter on test projects in the `Path to project(s)` field. Not sure if this is of any assistance in your case.

Comment: For anyone wanting an example filter, you can use something like `**/bin/**/*.Tests.dll` which will ensure only the DLLs in the `bin` folder are executed.  The last segment will need to be modified depending on how the test projects are named.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct/best answer. Setting the filter correctly is the way to go. Inspect the output in the pipeline carefully for clues. This is the filter that worked for me: https://gist.github.com/ManfredLange/0275b01bdbd6df61b352fe586a4b224d

Answer (score 42):

If anyone gets this after upgrading to .Net 5.0 it now creates a reference assembly in the `ref` folder, with the same name as the output assembly. You need to ignore this in your search criteria:
`!**/ref/**`

Comment: Another option is to disable the reference assembly generation by putting: <ProduceReferenceAssembly>false</ProduceReferenceAssembly> in the project file

Comment: Thanks you saved me!

Answer (score 4):

I got the same exception when I tried to run my unit test project from azure devops:
##[error]Unable to find C:\Users\Viktor\agent_work\2\s\Source\API\VCC_uTests\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\VCC_uTests.deps.json. Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk".

The issue was that there was 2 VCC.uTests.dll in my $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) folder,that vstest started based on my run unit tests pipe line step.

I could recognize it from the step log:

vstest.console.exe
"C:\Users\Viktor\agent_work\2\s\Source\API\VCC.uTests\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\VCC_uTests.dll"
"C:\Users\Viktor\agent_work\2\s\Source\API\VCC.uTests\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\VCC_uTests.dll"

Therefore, I had to modify my run test step search pattern:
**\bin$(BuildConfiguration)**VCC_uTests.dll

This solved my issue and the step ran successfully in my build pipeline.